# Extract strings from text file and write it to Excel

Tags: python, python-re

I was trying to write a Python script to extract texts from text file and write it into excel file.
The question is I do not know how to extract the strings next to equal.
I am new to Python, at this stage just manage to open the file.

The data looks like below:

```
ADD IUACCAREALST: AREA=RA, MCC="510", MNC="28", LAC="0x020a", RAC="0x68", RACRANGE="0x73", SUBRANGE=SPECIAL_IMSI_RANGE, BEGIMSI="511100001243", ENDIMSI="53110100270380", CTRLTYPE=REJECT, CAUSE=ROAMING_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_LA;

ADD IUACCAREALST: AREA=RA, MCC="510", MNC="28", LAC="0x01Fa", RAC="0x67", RACRANGE="0x63", SUBRANGE=SPECIAL_IMSI_RANGE, BEGIMSI="", ENDIMSI="", CTRLTYPE=REJECT, CAUSE=ROAMING_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_LA;
```

Output should be like below:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import re

fieldnames = ['AREA', 'MCC', 'MNC']

re_fields = re.compile(r'({})\s+=\s(.*)'.format('|'.join(fieldnames)), re.I)

with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames= fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()
```

Comment: What did you intend to do with `re_fields`? Do you know how to read data from a text file line by line?

Answer (score 0):

Your corrected pattern is [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/H5TPGx/1/)

I would break text like that into [BLOCKS](https://regex101.com/r/A58fud/1) and then find the matches in each block:

```
import csv
import re

fieldnames = ['AREA', 'MCC', 'MNC']

re_fields = re.compile(r'({})\s*=\s*([^,]+),'.format('|'.join(fieldnames)))

with open(fn) as f_input:
    data=f_input.read()
    
for block in re.finditer(r'(?<=ADD IUACCAREALST:)(.*?)(?=ADD IUACCAREALST:|\Z)', data, flags=re.S | re.M):
    print(re_fields.findall(block.group(1)))
```

Prints:

```
[('AREA', 'RA'), ('MCC', '"510"'), ('MNC', '"28"')]
[('AREA', 'RA'), ('MCC', '"510"'), ('MNC', '"28"')]
```

At that point, use each list of tuples to create a dict forming that csv record; write it to the csv file. Done!

Comment: Thanks Dawg, I'm pretty new to Python, tried it but didn't manage to get it work. Any chances if you could show me?